# The error when we rounding down and sum in $\sum_i \lfloor n/i \rfloor$ vs. $\sum_i n/i$.

Tags: number-theory, analysis, discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods, rounding-error

For some $x \in \mathbb R$ denote by $\lfloor x \rfloor := \sup\{ k \in \mathbb Z \mid k \le x \}$ the biggest integer smaller than $x$, the so called [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

Then in my textbook it is claimed that:

> $$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \lfloor \frac{n}{i} \rfloor \sim  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n}{i} $$
>   where the error as we go from $\lfloor n/i \rfloor$ to $n/i$ is smaller than $1$, hence also in the sum.

Why is the error in the sum smaller than $1$, surely the error between $\lfloor n/i \rfloor$ to $n/i$ is smaller than $1$, but I do not see that this holds true for the error between the sums $\sum_{i=1}^n \lfloor \frac{n}{i} \rfloor$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n}{i}$?

Comment: A more interesting question is how much the two sums differ without the 1/n in front.

Comment: Thats was what I was trying to determine, as I overlooked the $1/n$, so if you know it, feel free to give an answer! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sums (up to $n$) the error becomes $n$, and then you divide the sums by $n$, hence the error is $1$.

I believe you read over the $\frac{1}{n}$ part in the quote.

Comment: Oh yes, sometimes I am just blind... thank u!