# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n -\big\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\big\rfloor+\big\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\big\rfloor-\dots}{n}$, a Brilliant problem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I encounter a question when visiting [Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/problems/floor-limit/):

**Find**

$\space\space\space\space\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n$

$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n - \big \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \big \rfloor+ \big \lfloor \frac{n}{3} \big \rfloor - \big \lfloor \frac{n}{4} \big \rfloor + \dots}{n}$

$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\rfloor}{n}$

The answer in the website above doesn't really satisfies me, as the answer does not tell how the sequence converge and I doesn't understand how we can take subsequence $n_k=k!$ to solve the problem.

**I had some idea but doesn't seems to work:**

**1)** It is easy to show $$s_n=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{\big\lceil\frac{n}{2}\big\rceil}(\big\lfloor\frac{n}{2k-1}\big\rfloor-\big\lfloor\frac{n}{2k}\big\rfloor)}{n}$$

**2)** On the other hand,

$$s_n\approx\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{k}\to\ln2$$

So I am wondering how $s_n\approx$ the alternate hamonic series
$$\forall(n,k\in\mathbb N:n\ge k),\space\space\frac{n}{k}\in\Bigg[\bigg\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\bigg\rfloor,\bigg\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg(\frac{k-1}{k}\bigg)\Bigg]$$

I tried to look at the [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gahgebli4f), the sequence $s_n$ is very likely to converge to $\ln 2$, and the alternating harmonic series seems to be bounded by the graph of $s_n$ at most of the time.

**3)** Also I observed that $s_8=\frac{8-4+2-2+1-1+1-1}{8}=\frac{1}{2}$, the terms cancelled nicely, but I am afraid that the anlalogue is not generaly true for all $s_{2^k}$.

**4)** I have tried to use [Stolz–Cesàro Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), but doesn't seems useful neither.

**5)** I know that $\forall x,y\in\mathbb R:x+y\in\mathbb Z, \lfloor x\rfloor+\lceil y\rceil=x+y$, which maybe is useful since we may thus write $s_n$ in a more beautiful manner?

**6)** If there is no $(-1)^{k+1}$, I think we can treat $s_n$ as a Riemann sum, but well, ... , seems useless.

**7)** I have tried to think about how many terms of summand of $ns_n$ is integer.

**8)** I have tried to think $\big\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\big\rfloor$ as the number of positive integer multiple of $k$ that $\lt n$, and I then considered sets of number that is counted and uncounted respectively, but well, the question doesn't seems that easy.

> Does this help?
>   [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207604/formula-and-proof-for-the-sum-of-floor-and-ceiling-numbers) 
>   [(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Quotients) 
>   [(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2629666/the-error-when-we-rounding-down-and-sum-in-sum-i-lfloor-n-i-rfloor-vs-su)

Any help will be appreciate. Thank you!

> Remarks: I was wondering is there a deep subject studying this (if so references please). Can this (or variants) be represented as a simpler function?

Comment: (+1), this question takes "shows research effort" to a new level!

Comment: Why does the first link go to desmos instead of Brilliant?

Comment: Corrected. Thx.

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115824/rounding-is-asymptotically-useless

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

$$f(x)
= \mathbf{1}_{\{\text{$x > 0$ and $\lfloor 1/x \rfloor$ is odd}\}}
= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\{ 2i-1 \leq \frac{1}{x} < 2i \}}.
$$

Then by double counting, we find that

\begin{align*}
s_n
= \sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k-1} \bigg\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \bigg\rfloor
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k-1} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \mathbf{1}_{\{kj \leq n\}} \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k-1} \mathbf{1}_{\{kj \leq n\}}
 = \sum_{j=1}^{n} f\left(\frac{j}{n}\right).
\end{align*}

Now we utilize the following lemma:

> **Lemma.** Let $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be Riemann integrable. Then
>   $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{n} f\left(\frac{j}{n}\right)\frac{1}{n} = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, dx. $$

From this, we know that $s_n/n$ converges and

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{s_n}{n}
= \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, dx
= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{2i-1} - \frac{1}{2i} \right)
= \log 2. $$

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your notation in line 1: How can you sum from $i=1$ to $\infty$ but also requiring {$2i-1\le\frac{1}{x}\lt 2i$}?

Comment: @TonyMa, The notation $\mathbf{1}_{\{\cdots\}}$ yields $1$ if $\cdots$ is true and $0$ otherwise. I just partitioned the set $$A = \{ x \in [0, 1] : \text{$x > 0$ and $\lfloor 1/x \rfloor$ is odd}\}$$ into $$A = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} \{ x \in (0, 1] : 2i-1 \leq (1/x) < 2i \},$$ which yields the first line. In particular, at most one term in $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\{ 2i-1 \leq \frac{1}{x} < 2i \}}$ is non-zero.

Comment: Oic, I used to use the notation $\sum_{i\in\mathbb N:2i-1\le\frac{1}{x}\lt2i}1$

Comment: how to prove $f$ is riemann integrable on $[0,1]$? I only have heard that if $f$ is constant for all but finite point, then $f$ is riemann integrable.

Comment: @TonyMa, Since the discontinuities of $f$ occur at $\{\frac{1}{n}:n\geq 1\}\cup\{0\}$, it is not hard to directly establish the Riemann integrability. But of course we can count on a sledgehammer method; it can be proved that a bounded function is Riemann integrable if and only if the set of discontinuities is measure-zero.

Comment: I think I understand it. How a wonderful solution! I have think up the idea of this approach but I haven't try to use $f(\frac{j}{n})$ to make it be a Riemann sum. Truly beautiful. Thank so much

Comment: @TonyMa Glad it helped :)

Comment: this is smart! Is there a reason that you think of a Riemann sum here ?

Answer (score 7):

**Elementary high school approach**

One can show immediately with the squeeze theorem that
$$L_1=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor}\frac{1}{2n}\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{k}\right\rfloor-\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor}\frac{1}{n}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor\right)=\log(2),$$

using the simple fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(H_{2n}-H_n)=\log(2)$.

But guess what! Your limit is

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{2n}\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{k}\right\rfloor-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor\right)=L_1,$$ 
and therefore you can use the first limit to calculate your initial limit and then show that the sum of the remaining terms tends to $0$, which is straightforward.

**Adding some steps requested by OP**

WLOG, for the comfort of calculations, we can replace in the initial limit $n$ by $2n$, and using the double inequality with floor function $x\ge\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor\ge x-1$, we have

$$H_{2\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}\ge\sum_{k=1}^{2\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}\frac{1}{2n}\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{k}\right\rfloor\ge H_{2\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}-\frac{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}{n}$$

$$-H_{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}+\frac{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}{n}\ge-\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}\frac{1}{n}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor\ge-H_{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor},$$
that give
$$H_{2\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}-H_{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}+\frac{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}{n}\ge\sum_{k=1}^{2\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}\frac{1}{2n}\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{k}\right\rfloor-\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}\frac{1}{n}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor\ge H_{2\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}-H_{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}-\frac{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}{n}.$$
Letting $n\to\infty$ you get the value of the limit $L_1$. If denoting $\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor=m$, we have the type of limit mentioned above, $\lim_{m\to\infty}(H_{2m}-H_m)=\log(2)$.

Your limit, after replacing $n$ by $2n$, is

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{1}{2n}\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{k}\right\rfloor=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{2n}\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{k}\right\rfloor-2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2n}\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{2k}\right\rfloor\right)$$ 
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{2n}\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{k}\right\rfloor-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor\right).$$

What's left to do? Using in the last limit that limit $L_1$ calculated above.
 $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{2n}\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{k}\right\rfloor-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor\right)$$ 
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor}\frac{1}{2n}\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{k}\right\rfloor+\sum_{k=2\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{2n}\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{k}\right\rfloor-\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor}\frac{1}{n}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor-\sum_{k=\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor+1}^n\frac{1}{n}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor\right)$$
$$=\underbrace{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor}\frac{1}{2n}\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{k}\right\rfloor-\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor}\frac{1}{n}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor\right)}_{\displaystyle \log(2)}+\underbrace{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=2\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{2n}\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{k}\right\rfloor-\sum_{k=\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor+1}^n\frac{1}{n}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor\right)}_{\displaystyle 0}$$
$$=\log(2),$$
and the limit tending to $0$ can be done by *arranging* the sums under the limit under the form of an alternating sum and then squeezing the sum.

**Further explanations on the limit tending to $0$**

It's clear that 
$$0\le\sum_{k=2\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{2n}\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{k}\right\rfloor-\sum_{k=\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor+1}^n\frac{1}{n}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor=\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=\underbrace{2\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor+1}_{m}}^{2n}(-1)^{k-1}\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{k}\right\rfloor$$
$$=\frac{1}{2n}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{m}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{m+1}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{m+2}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{m+3}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{m+4}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{m+5}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{m+6}\right\rfloor-\cdots\right)$$
$$\le\frac{1}{2n}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{m}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{m+1}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{m+1}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{m+3}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{m+3}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{m+5}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{m+5}\right\rfloor-\cdots\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2n}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{m}\right\rfloor-1\right)=\frac{1}{2n}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{2\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor+1}\right\rfloor-1\right),$$
where letting $n\to\infty$, we obviously get $0$ which accounts for the limit tending to $0$ in my solution.

**A final remark**

One should have dealt from the very beginning with this part of the limit tending to $0$ since we had it in the form with the alternating sum as expected.

Comment: Maybe you can add some step? such as how to use squeeze theorem and how my limit is equal to $L_1$? Thank you

Comment: @TonyMa Is everything crystal clear now?

Comment: Well...Sounds pretty cool. I get your idea and I think I might study it carefully later. But do you just proof one of the subsequences $s_{2k}\to\ln2$? How about $s_{2k-1}$? Or do u know it also converges to $\ln 2$ for sure? Does it have a similar proof?

Comment: @TonyMa That's why I started with writing *WLOG* (without loss of generality). $s_{2k-1}$ follows the same line of proving the limit.

Answer (score 6):

Note that
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor-\frac{1}{n/2}\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\left\lfloor\frac{n/2}{k}\right\rfloor=\frac{D(n)}{n}-\frac{D(n/2)}{n/2}.$$
where 
$D(x)= \sum_{k\geq 1}^{n}\left\lfloor\frac{x}{k}\right\rfloor$
is the [divisor summatory function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function). It is known that 
$$D(x) = x\ln(x) + x(2\gamma -1) + O(\sqrt{x})\implies \frac{D(x)}{x} = \ln(x) + (2\gamma -1) + o(1)$$
(see also [Dirichlet's Divisor Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2062/dirichlets-divisor-problem)).
Hence, as $n$ goes to $+\infty$,
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor=
\ln(n)-\ln(n/2)+o(1)\to \ln(2).$$

Comment: For first sentence, do you assume $n$ is even? For second, do you mean $\ln$ instead of $\log$?

Comment: @TonyMa usually $\log$ and $\ln$ are used interchangeably.

Comment: @TonyMa No, $n$ is any integer number. I mean $\ln$.